# Rails3 calling certain action of certain controller by button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, button, controller, action

On the view pages there is a tag <%= submit_tag "Some text" %> which renders the correspondent controller's 'create' action(isn't it?). Is it possible to render action of another controller's by the button click?

Answer (score 0):

That's possible, but not with the `submit_tag` method. You want to alter the corresponding `form_tag` method, which accepts an argument like `'/posts'` or `'/posts/your_action'`. So you could do:

```
<%= form_tag('/posts') %>
…
<%= submit_tag %>
```

Regards

Tobias

Comment: this code creates a button with action equal to the current url

Answer (score 0):

Check [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helpers or the module itself

Comment: Both of them are useless if you want to submit some data